# Angular2: How to display data in html format in angular2 data binding?

Tags: angular

I have product data from database contains title, description...
The description is in html format string, like this:

```
<b>Name:</b> iPhone 5;<br>
<b>Membery:</b> 8GB;<br>
<b>Condition:</b> Brand new;<br />
```

if supposed to be displayed like this:

**Name:** iPhone 5;

**Memory:** 8GB;

**Condition:** Brand new

But when I use data-binding in Angular2: {{product.description}}, it displays like pure text:

```
<b>Name:</b> iPhone 5; <br /><b>Memory:</b> 8GB;<br /><b>Condition:</b> Brand new;<br />
```

How should I display it correctly as html ? there is no html filter for the binding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can bind to `innerHTML`:

```
<div [innerHTML]="product.description"></div>
```